# Wordpress: Some pages still 404ing after fixing changed URL

Tags: wordpress

This is the site I'm working on: http://willowknows.com/index/
I was able to fix this to show back up again and let me login after changing the URL in settings. But the other pages that link to other parts of the site are still 404ing.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please clarify. Can you login? Have you tried updating the permalink settings?

Comment: Why is this tagged under WordPress? You're running a Shopify site.

Answer (score 0):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules

this might help.. 
but add it.. refresh a page.. and than remove the code again. Otherwise it will flush on every request and slow down wordpress.